# A Taylor theorem for Hölder continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, holder-spaces

Let $ C^{m,s}_{b} $ be the space of bounded function $ u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which satisfies 
\begin{alignat*}{2}
\bigg| u^{(m)}(x) - u^{(m)}(y) \bigg| \leq C | x - y |^{s}.
\end{alignat*}
I'm looking for a Taylor - type theorem which could bound the remainder of the following polynomial 
$$ u(x) = \sum_{k \geq N} \frac{(x-y)^{k}}{k!} u^{(k)}(y) + R_{N}(x) $$
by $$| R_{N}(x) | \leq |x-y|^{m+s}.$$
In the simple case that $ N=1 $ I know that
$$ u(x) = u(y) + u'(y)(x-y) + \int_{0}^{1} \Big( u'\big(y + t(x-y) \big) - u'(y) \Big)dt (x-y) .$$
But I have yet been successful in finding the right expression for the arbitrary case. Could anyone please shed some light on the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the Taylor formula of order $m-1$ with the Lagrange remainder
$$
u(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{(x-y)^{k}}{k!} u^{(k)}(y) + \frac{(x-y)^{m}}{m!} u^{(m)}(\xi),
$$
where $\xi$ is between $y$ and $x$, and rewrite it as
$$
u(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{(x-y)^{k}}{k!} u^{(k)}(y) + \frac{(x-y)^{m}(u^{(m)}(\xi)-u^{(m)}(y))}{m!}.
$$
Using the Holder condition for the remainder one has 
$$
|R_m(x)|=\left|\frac{(x-y)^{m}(u^{(m)}(\xi)-u^{(m)}(y))}{m!} \right|\le C\frac{|x-y|^{m+s}}{m!}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Happy Xmas!