A uniform bounded in a bounded $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}$
I’m in trouble with some inequality. I want to prove that
$$\|\Delta u-\frac{c_1}{\epsilon^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon})(u(y)-u(x))dy\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq C\epsilon^\alpha,$$
where $u\in C^{2,\alpha}(\mathbb{R})$ [Holder Continuous Function], $0<\alpha<1$. The normalization constant $c_1$ is $c_1^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)z^2dz$ and $J$ is a positive even continuous function in $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support in $[-N,N]$, $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Firstly, I tried to fix the variables to use taylor’s serie:
$$\Delta u-\frac{c_1}{\epsilon^3}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon})(u(y)-u(x))dy =\Delta u-\frac{c_1}{\epsilon^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)(u(x-\epsilon z)-u(x)))dz$$
$$=\Delta u-\frac{c_1}{\epsilon^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)[u_x(x)(-\epsilon z)+\frac{1}{2}\Delta u \epsilon^2z^2)+E(x,\epsilon z)]dz $$
$$= \Delta u+\frac{c_1}{\epsilon}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)zu_x(x)dz- c_1\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)z^2\frac{1}{2}\Delta u(x)dz+ \frac{c_1}{\epsilon^2}\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z) E(x,\epsilon z)]dz.$$
We have that the second term is zero because J(z)z is a odd in $\mathbb{R}$ and, by $c_1$’s definition, $c_1\int_{\mathbb{R}}J(z)z^2\frac{1}{2}\Delta u(x)dz=\Delta u(x)$. Now, the problem is the last term. I tried to consider the taylor’s remainder as $E(x,\epsilon z)=\Delta u(x-\frac{\epsilon}{2}z)\frac{(\frac{\epsilon}{2} z)^2}{2!}$ and $\pm u_{xx}(x)$ to apply the definition of $C^{2,\alpha}$ to get $\epsilon^{\alpha}$. Some type?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050275/a-taylor-theorem-for-h%C3%B6lder-continuous-function

may be useful..
